a frame render time toast alway show
Im using rn 0.75.4 with new arch , when app is hung or lag. or about to crash. there come out a popup show. [appanme]Debug xxxx ms. what is this. and how to turn off. app is release build
enter image description here
what is this. and how to turn off
